# Warbler executable won't start

Tags: jruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jrubyonrails, warbler

I have some trouble packing my JRuby-application with warbler and running it.

I've created a simple sqlite3-app with one model which works fine when running via `jruby -S rails s`.

However, if I try packing it with `jruby -S warble executable war` the packed Winstone-server crashes with

```
[Winstone 2010/12/20 10:33:48] - Beginning extraction from war file
[Winstone 2010/12/20 10:33:50] - WARNING: The Servlet 2.4/2.5 spec XSD was unavailable inside the winstone classpath. Will be retrieved from the web if required (slow)
[Winstone 2010/12/20 10:33:50] - No webapp classes folder found - C:\Temp\winstone908137348044208817webroot\sqlite-test.war\WEB-INF\classes
[webapp 2010/12/20 10:33:51] - Warning: error application could not be initialized org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: no such file to load -- builtin/core_ext/symbol

    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.newRuntime(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:85)
    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.createApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:177)
    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.newErrorApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:127)
    at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.init(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:45)
    at org.jruby.rack.PoolingRackApplicationFactory.init(PoolingRackApplicationFactory.java:50)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:40)
    at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.<init>(WebAppConfiguration.java:889)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:73)
    at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
    at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:196)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Main.launchWinstone(Main.java:67)
    at Main.start(Main.java:72)
    at Main.main(Main.java:97)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: no such file to load -- builtin/core_ext/symbol
    at (unknown).new(:1)
    at (unknown).(unknown)(:1)
```

Where does this come from, and how do I get this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in JRuby 1.5.5 and earlier versions that affect running the executable jar on Windows and in paths that contain spaces. See [JRUBY-4774](http://bugs.jruby.org/4774) or [WARBLER-15](http://kenai.com/jira/browse/WARBLER-15).

Try upgrading JRuby to 1.5.6 (`gem update jruby-jars`), rebuild the war file, and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've upgraded to JRuby 1.5.6 and jruby-rack 1.0.4 and this error seems fixed. Although, running the war from a path with spaces in it still doesn't work, it fails with `The warfile supplied is unavailable or invalid`